# I am unable to run espresso tests in Android version 7 and above

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am unable to run espresso tests on android emulators or devices with Android version 7 and above. I get the following error as soon as the tests start:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field EXACT of type Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap; in class Lcom/google/thirdparty/publicsuffix/PublicSuffixPatterns; or its superclasses (declaration of 'com.google.thirdparty.publicsuffix.PublicSuffixPatterns' appears in /data/app/com.amazon.now.test-EKq8w8LCxbZxutgNh5hxog==/base.apk)
at com.google.common.net.InternetDomainName.findPublicSuffix(Unknown Source:21)
at com.google.common.net.InternetDomainName.<init>(Unknown Source:89)
at com.google.common.net.InternetDomainName.from(Unknown Source:8)
```

I have searched all over the internet and found a similar issue in GoogleGuava package https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-538.

But looks like it is resolved.
These are the espresso and GoogleGuava versions that I use.

```
GoogleGuava = r16;
    AndroidSupportPackage-annotations = 26.0.2;
    AndroidSupportPackage-v4 = 26.0.2;
    AndroidSupportPackage-v7 = 26.0.2;
    AndroidSupportPackage-v7-recyclerview = 26.0.2;
    AndroidSupportPackage-compat = 26.0.2;

    # UI Testing dependencies
    AndroidSupportTestPackage-runner = 0.5;
    AndroidSupportTestPackage-espresso-core = 2.2.2;
    AndroidSupportTestPackage-espresso-idling-resource = 2.2.2;
    AndroidSupportTestPackage-espresso-web = 2.2.2;
    AndroidSupportTestPackage-espresso-intents = 2.2.2;
    AndroidSupportTestPackage-espresso-contrib = 2.2.2;
    AndroidSupportTestPackage-uiautomator-v18 = 2.1.2;
```